# Connection stall when addressing unknown server ActiveMQ

Tags: java, queue, jms, activemq-classic

I use ActiveMQ and JMS in Java.

When i send messages using this url:

```
"failover:(tcp://host:61616)?connection.sendTimeout=1000&startupMaxReconnectAttempts=1"
```

everything works fine as long as "host" is a known server in which i have connection to and of course have an ActiveMQ.

The problem is when i try to send message to an unknown server that i have no relation with - no connection, the send stalls for considerable amount of time.

I want to configure the url so that kind of stall will not happen. i tried the timeout as shown in the example, but it dont work. I also tried the soConnectionTimeout which dont work either.

This stall is causing produces to stall which is a big problem.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you experience the stall with the host being an FQDN or an IP; i.e. could it be a DNS timeout?

Comment: @Anders R. Bystrup I am sending the host IP. didnt tried to send DNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding on the 'connectionTimeout' option to the URI as documented [here](http://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference.html)?  The timeout value controls how long before the connect call fails.

Comment: I am using failover protocol and have tried the timeout option which dont help in this scnario

Comment: Wrong option, you need to set TCP level transport option to control how long the socket waits.  That's a TCP transport option, read the page linked in my answer.